# S3 create bucket mandatory tag policy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to apply mandatory tags restriction condition on S3 bucket. But below statement always throwing access denied error.

Steps which I follow while creating new bucket.

1. Add Bucket name
2. Add tag "Environment" and value "Development"
3. Click on Create Bucket but it's throwing access denied error.

Custom Policy Statement :

{

```
        "Sid": "PermissionsRelatedToBucketOperations",

        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Environment": [
                    "",
                    "Development",
                    "Production"
                ]
            },
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:TagKeys": [
                    "Environment"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

However , I have added s3:CreateBucket and s3:PutBucketTagging actions with above condition but still it's not working.

"Action": 
[
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketTagging"
            ]

Snapshot :
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The CreateBucket action does not let you to put tags on the bucket.

I am assuming you are working in the S3 Console. When you click on "Create Bucket", it is running (at least) two requests: CreateBucket and then PutBucketTagging. Your policy only allows it to run CreateBucket when the request includes those tags. However, the request for CreateBucket does not include those tags (because they wouldn't do anything).

Comment: Hi Joey, have added the PutBucketTagging but it's not working .

Comment: It's not that you are missing the permission, it is that your CreateBucket permission will not allow you to do anything, since no CreateBucket request will have any request tags.

Comment: Is there any way to apply mandatory tag while creating S3 bucket. I have tested the same scenarios with EC2 and mandatory tag is working fine for me.

Comment: The CreateBucket action does not accept any tags, so you can't have a condition based on what the tags are. This is not possible.

Comment: A possible option is to make a lambda that has permissions to CreateBucket and PutBucketTagging and just give the user permission to invoke that lambda, but I am not sure if this fits what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question edit was in response to my last comment, but when you press "Create Bucket" in the console, multiple API calls are made and multiple permissions are needed. Specifically, the CreateBucket call does not take tags, instead those are set by the PutBucketTagging call. You can see this in detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html).